# Odd many-to-many behavior in symfony 1.4 forms with Doctrine

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine, many-to-many, symfony-1.4

I am encountering unexpected behavior with form processing, symfony 1.4 with Doctrine. I have a table which has a many-to-many relationship to itself:

```
Person:
  [...]
  relations:
    Teachers:
      class: Person
      refClass: PersonTeacher
      local: student_id
      foreign: teacher_id
      foreignAlias: Students

PersonTeacher:
  columns:
    teacher_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
    student_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
```

In Person, I have a method which gets called in PersonForm for use in a custom widget:

```
public function getTeachersOrderByName()
{
  $q = Doctrine::getTable('Person')
    ->createQuery('t')
    ->leftJoin('t.Students s')
    ->where('s.id = ?', $this->getId())
    ->orderBy('t.last_name, t.first_name ASC');

  return $q->execute();
}
```

Without that method call, Doctrine correctly INSERTs and DELETEs records from PersonTeacher. But when I call that method from the PersonForm, the following UPDATE is run upon saving the form [taken from the logs]:

```
Doctrine_Connection->update(object('PersonTeacherTable'), array('student_id' => '9'), array('teacher_id' => '9', 'student_id' => '6'))
```

which throws

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 columns teacher_id, student_id are not unique
```

Backtrace:

```
at Doctrine_Connection_Statement->execute(array('9', '9', '6'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php line 1042 ...
at Doctrine_Connection->exec('UPDATE person_teacher SET student_id = ? WHERE teacher_id = ? AND student_id = ?', array('9', '9', '6'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection.php line 653 ...
at Doctrine_Connection->update(object('PersonTeacherTable'), array('student_id' => '9'), array('teacher_id' => '9', 'student_id' => '6'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection/UnitOfWork.php line 534 ...
at Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->update(object('PersonTeacher'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection/UnitOfWork.php line 89 ...
at Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->saveGraph(object('PersonTeacher'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php line 1718 ...
at Doctrine_Record->save(object('Doctrine_Connection_Sqlite'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Collection.php line 910 ...
at Doctrine_Collection->save(object('Doctrine_Connection_Sqlite'), 1)
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection/UnitOfWork.php line 136 ...
at Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->saveGraph(object('Person'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php line 1718 ...
at Doctrine_Record->save(object('Doctrine_Connection_Sqlite'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Collection.php line 910 ...
at Doctrine_Collection->save(object('Doctrine_Connection_Sqlite'), )
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection/UnitOfWork.php line 445 ...
at Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->saveAssociations(object('Person'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Connection/UnitOfWork.php line 142 ...145.
at Doctrine_Connection_UnitOfWork->saveGraph(object('Person'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/vendor/doctrine/Doctrine/Record.php line 1718 ...
at Doctrine_Record->save(object('Doctrine_Connection_Sqlite'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/form/addon/sfFormObject.class.php line 161 ...
at sfFormObject->doSave(object('Doctrine_Connection_Sqlite'))
in SF_ROOT_DIR/lib/form/doctrine/base/BasePersonForm.class.php line 116 ...
at BasePersonForm->doSave(object('Doctrine_Connection_Sqlite'))
in SF_SYMFONY_LIB_DIR/form/addon/sfFormObject.class.php line 130 ...
```

This only occurs when the many-to-many refers to the same table. I also have a one-to-many referring to its own table, and it works correctly.

This ring any bells?

Comment: Does the constraint that fails seem correct to you? I agree that the pair (teacher_id, student_id) should be unique in the refClass table, but teacher_id alone should not be unique, nor should student_id. Could you please check your table structure and show us what constraint were put on it?

Comment: @greg0ire: The only constraint created in my SQLite database is the PK (confirmed in the symfony-generated schema.sql), so I presume the error refers to the PK. The problem is that Doctrine_Connection::update() should not be called at all - the PersonTeacher records should only be INSERTed and DELETEd at need, which is indeed what happens, until I try calling my getTeachersOrderByName() method. That somehow opens the door to the mysterious update() call.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE person_teacher (teacher_id INTEGER, student_id INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(teacher_id, student_id));`

Comment: @yitznewton: in you stack trace, I can see "TeacherPerson", in your schema file, I can only see "PersonTeacher", used as a refClass... how come? Is there another refClass, or would it rather be a doctrine internal mechanism?

Comment: @greg0ire I apologize, I changed the name of that table at one point, and the trace is apparently from before the change - it should all be PersonTeacher, and still fails.

Comment: @yitznewton: the error occurs before the delete/insert statements (take a look at the `saveAssociations()` method). Doctrine tries to save teachers (or is it students?), and one of them has a modified PersonTeacher relation, so it tries to update it first, provoking this failure. Could you use step-by-step debugging to confirm/precise this scenario?

Comment: @yitznewton: By the way, what you are dealing with is [a non equal nested relation](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/defining-models%3Arelationships%3Ajoin-table-associations%3Aself-referencing-nest-relations%3Anon-equal-nest-relations/en) As you can see in the linked page, the columns are explicitly specified as members of the primary key, maybe you shoud do so in your schema?

Comment: @greg0ire: WRT primary key in schema, they are, I have updated the question to include those lines. WRT before the delete/insert, my IDE debugging is working with my app but not yet with the symfony libraries (including Doctrine UnitOfWork); however, I see from the symfony log that you appear to be correct. Let's say my Person is linked to Teacher 6, and I select 6 and 9 on the form. The INSERT for 9 is never performed, only the attempted UPDATE on 6.

Comment: I see that the same thing is happening if I try to add a form field for the inverted relationship: `$this->widgetSchema['students_list'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('multiple' => true, 'model' => 'Person')); $this->setDefault('students_list', $this->object->Students->getPrimaryKeys());`

Comment: @yitznewton: the only link I can see between the Teacher and the PersonTeacher would occur because of the left join. Have you tried without it? If it is not the problem, could you show use the code that handles the post?

Comment: @greg0ire: not sure what you're asking; that join is called in PersonForm to populate a custom widget. If I use the stock widget  specified in BasePersonForm by `symfony doctrine:build` it works correctly with INSERTs and DELETEs. So yes, this join query somehow directly or indirectly causes this problem, but I don't know Doctrine/symfony internals well enough to understand why a SELECT should impact what happens later in processing the form.

Comment: @yitznewton: I'm asking you to keep the method with the query, but to drop the left join query part, because I suspect the problem comes from this part of the query (and not from the select part). In the code that handles the post, I think that the form is rebuilt with the same widgets, and that it is populated from the request, creating objects and relations. And I think the left join part might add an unwanted relation. Not sure at all, but it is all I can think of for the moment.

Comment: @greg0ire: yes - when I eliminate the join, the error does not occur. And yes, the form is rebuilt with widgets. My problem, then, is why does doing `Doctrine::getTable()::getQuery()` with a join, in a (so I thought) isolated method in **building** the form, affect the process of **processing** and submitting a form? I'm new to Doctrine, but this doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @yitznewton: Before processing the form, you have to build it again, right? I guess the explanation would be that the widget is used to fill a relation, that is turn an array of ids coming from the request into a Doctrine_Collection of Doctrine_Record objects ready to be saved. Does that make sense? It's a guess, I'm not 100% sure it actually is like this.

Comment: I think this is related to http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/5849

Comment: @greg0ire: Yes, it's a symfony/Doctrine bug, known for over a year, also at http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-329 grrr... time to go Doctrine-diving. Thank you greg0ire! Your defining this as non-equal nested relation enabled me to find the tickets.

Comment: @yitznewton: glad you enventually found something, this is good to know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in Doctrine and/or symfony, over a year old:

- http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/5849
- http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/9398
- http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DC-329

Comment: The h2aEqualable workaround in the Doctrine ticket seems to work for me.